# Blender Bone Constraint Issue

Tags: blender, minecraft

https://streamable.com/fjeaa

[image]

I was creating a basic rig and I wanted to add ankles. I don't want to copy the z location because it'd just look bad. Without the Z axis enabled it bugs out like crazy. I've been at this for a few days now and it makes me want to just give up.

Any ideas on how to fix this?

Windows 10, Blender 2.79

Comment: What does this have to do with [Minecraft]?

Comment: Sorry for a late reply but I'm using it for a minecraft rig. Look at the streamable link.